# How to find the expected value before a bitarray is full?

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-series, hash-function

If I have a bitarray of size $m$ with all $0$'s initially and one universal hash function $h: U \rightarrow [m]$ where each index in the bitarray has $\frac{1}{m}$ probability of being flipped to 1, then the probability of any index $i$ in two bitarrays $x$ and $y$ having the same bit flipped is: $P[h(x_i)=h(y_i)]=\frac{1}{m}$.

Now, if I have a binary tree like shown below where the root is just the union of all inserted bit arrays, the right subtree is the union of `b1` and `b2`, and the left tree is the union of `b1`, then the probability of choosing the right subtree for insertion (based on the bitwise AND) will be greater. For instance, if I were to insert `b4=00100` into the below tree then the probability of choosing right subtree will be $\frac{2}{5}$ (although the bitwise AND is $0$ for both subtrees in this case).

How can I find the expected number of insertions before a subtree get's full? I know that the expected number of insertions before one bit array gets full is $\sum_{i}^{m}\mathbb{E}(X_i) =\sum_{i}^{m}\frac{1}{m} = m$, but the tricky part for me is that there is a probability of either subtrees getting picked and this would increase the expectation (I think).

```
insertions: b1=10000, b2=01000, b3=00001 based on bitwise AND

    11001 \\root with union of all bit arrays. b1 is left, while b2 and b3 is right
    /  \
   /    \
10000  01001
```

Comment: "then the probability of choosing the right subtree for insertion (based on the bitwise AND) will be greater." Why?

Comment: because then you are not restricted by only one filter and have more insertions.

Comment: I am afraid nobody understands you. Try to rewrite the question in an understandable way.

Comment: OK. will do that.